# event and effect as variables(jQuery)

Tags: jquery, events, variables

I am working on a jquery plugin, and to save time/space i want to use as much as possible variables, but if i try to replace an event of effect for an variable the code stops to work.

Is it possible to use variables for this?

The idea:

```
jQuery('#id').fadeIn(200);

var myEffect = fadeIn

jQuery('#id').myEffect(200);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bracket notation.

```
jQuery('#id')[myEffect](200);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/dVZBE/).

Comment: along with placing quotes around the function name: `var myEffect = 'fadeIn';`